# How to stop changing storage class to Glacier by S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

First of all I created lifecycle method that transfers objects older than 1 day to Glacier, but when I realized that I can't access then to that files outside.
So, I removed this lifecycle rule and restore all objects from Glacier to S3.
Despite this still every day some random files are changing storage class to Glacier. 
How can I fix this?